# Create new dropdown list with result from dropdown list selection php mysql database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, database

Ok .. here is the thing which is probably very easy to fix but unfortunatly not for me.

What I try to create is this:

I have 2 dropdown lists. List one consist of data straight from a database table.
Nothing fancy about that. I am just pulling them in with a SELECT query etc.

The second list is empty for now, but I would like that dropdown list be automatically filled with data that is related through id's by the selected item from my first dropdown list.

Here is the code:

html page with form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="form.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
             <form action="create_account.php" method="post">
                <ul style="list-style: none;">
                    <li>
                        <label>District:</label>
                        <select name="district" id="district">
                            <option id="0"> -- Selecteer District --</option>
                            <option id="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
                            <option id="Arnhem">Arnhem</option>
                            <option id="Assen">Assen</option>
                            <option id="Groningen">Groningen</option>
                            <option id="Leeuwarden">Leeuwarden</option>
                            <option id="Rotterdam">Rotterdam</option>
                            <option id="Sittard">Sittard</option>
                            <option id="Tilburg">Tilburg</option>
                            <option id="Utrecht">Utrecht</option>
                            <option id="Antillen">Antillen</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>Gemeente:</label>
                        <select name="gemeente" id="gemeente">
                            <option id="0"> -- Selecteer Gemeente --</option>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </form>
        </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the json page:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array();

if (isset($_GET['districtid'])) 
{
    //vul hier je database gebuikersnaam en ww in
    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Could not connect: " .     mysql_error());
    //vul hier je mysql db naam in
    mysql_select_db("my_db");

    $qry = mysql_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM gemeente WHERE district_id = " + $_GET['districtid']);

    $result = mysql_query($qry);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_NUM)) {
        array_push($response, $row);
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    $response[0]['id'] = 0;
    $response[0]['gemeente'] = ' -- Selecteer Gemeente --';
    echo json_encode($response);
}

?>
```

And here is the ajax file:

```
$("#district").change(function() {
    $.getJSON("json.php?districtid="+$(this).val(), function(data) {
        $("#gemeente").empty();
        $.each(data, function(){
            $("#gemeente").append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.gemeente +'</option>');
        });
    });
});
```

I can't seem to get it working.

So if there is somebody out there that can help me out, I realy appreciate it.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: `console.log(data)` before `$("#gemeente").empty();` your ajax file. and share with us this result

Comment: $("#district").change(function() {
        $.getJSON("json.php?districtid="+$(this).val(), function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            // $("#gemeente").empty();
            // $.each(data, function(){
            //     $("#gemeente").append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.gemeente +'</option>');
            // });
        });
    });

There was no ouput:-(

Comment: try it and let me know. `$.ajax({
  context: this,
  url: $(this).attr('action'),
  type: 'POST',
  data: {district:$(this).val()},
  dataType: 'json'
 }).done(function (data) {
  console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function(){
            $("#gemeente").append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.gemeente +'</option>');
        });
 }).fail(function (data) {
  console.log('failed');
 });`

Comment: Sadly no result. No automatic console message after selecting an item from the first dropdown box :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working example, please check.

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#district").change(function() {
            $.getJSON("json.php?districtid="+$(this).val(), function(data) {
                $("#gemeente").empty();
                $.each(data, function(){
                    $("#gemeente").append('<option value="'+ this.id +'">'+ this.gemeente +'</option>');
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="create_account.php" method="post">
            <ul style="list-style: none;">
                <li>
                    <label>District:</label>
                    <select name="district" id="district">
                        <option id="0"> -- Selecteer District --</option>
                        <option id="Amsterdam">Amsterdam</option>
                        <option id="Arnhem">Arnhem</option>
                        <option id="Assen">Assen</option>
                        <option id="Groningen">Groningen</option>
                        <option id="Leeuwarden">Leeuwarden</option>
                        <option id="Rotterdam">Rotterdam</option>
                        <option id="Sittard">Sittard</option>
                        <option id="Tilburg">Tilburg</option>
                        <option id="Utrecht">Utrecht</option>
                        <option id="Antillen">Antillen</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label>Gemeente:</label>
                    <select name="gemeente" id="gemeente">
                        <option id="0"> -- Selecteer Gemeente --</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
            </ul>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Here is your json.php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$response = array();

if (isset($_GET['districtid'])){
//vul hier je database gebuikersnaam en ww in
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$qry = "SELECT * FROM gemeente WHERE district_id = '".$_GET['districtid']."'";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $qry);  //mysql_query($qry);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)) {
    array_push($response, $row);
}

echo json_encode($response);
} else {
$response[0]['id'] = 0;
$response[0]['gemeente'] = ' -- Selecteer Gemeente --';
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```